# PhantomJs not giving full response

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to get response from following URL using phantomjs:-

```
https://www.trivago.com/api/v1/bin/accommodation/2891353/deals?iPathId=34812&iRoomType=1&aRooms=&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2017-05-24&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2017-05-25&bSharedRooms=false
```

phantomjs Code:-

```
var system = require('system');
var webPage = require('webpage');

var page = webPage.create();


var url = system.args[1];

page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
};


page.open(url, function (status) {
    var content = page.content;

    console.log(content);
   phantom.exit();
});
```

But I am getting only `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` as response instead of full response.  What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I opened your link in the Google Chrome and a binary file was downloaded.

Headers check confirmed that:

```
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 4160
content-type: application/octet-stream
```

PhantomJS can only open HTML pages, therefore you don't get response in your script, or any page structure.

Seeing as this API does not require any credentials, why not just download deals file via wget/cURL or just the language of your choice?

Comment: I want to do it with phantomjs only.

Comment: At the time PhantomJS does not support downloading files. There were experimental unofficial branches with support of downnloading though, so you could try to find and use them.